# AlphaAnimation does not go to 1.0

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I want to animate a view with an AlphaAnimation but I encounter a problem.

Before I start the animation, my view has an alpha of 0.5 and I want to increase the alpha to 1.0 then decrease it back to 0.5.

So :

1. Original state is 0.5
2. Animate from 0.5 to 1.0
3. Go back from 1.0 to 0.5

The problem is that the animation from 0.5 to 1.0 do not work as expected. I think that the animation works like this :

> 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25
>
> 0.5 * 1.0 = 0.5
>
> Result of point 2 : The view goes from alpha 0.25 to 0.5 instead of 0.5 to 1.0

I tried to set the alpha to 1.0 with myView.setAlpha(1.0) just before the animation starts but when I do that, the view blink just before the animation begins.

Here is the code :

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f);
alphaAnimation1.setDuration(200);

AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
alphaAnimation2.setDuration(200);
alphaAnimation2.setStartOffset(200);

myView.startAnimation(alphaAnimation1);
myView.startAnimation(alphaAnimation2);
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong and how I can change the alpha from 0.5 to 1.0 ?

Comment: can you please post the code ?

Comment: It seems both your animations run at the same time!? So while one animation tries to set alpha from 0.5 to 1, the other animation tries to set it from 1 to 0.5... at the same time.

Comment: The second animation starts 200ms after the first one thanks to alphaAnimation2.setStartOffset(200);